# Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 10 nodes produced errors; first error: object not found

Tags: r, parallel-processing, boot

I am trying to use parallel computing within the boot function in R. I am using Windows. Hence I used the "snow" option.

```
library(parallel)
  replications = 10
  
  mycores= detectCores(all.tests = FALSE, logical = TRUE)
  cl <- makeCluster(mycores-1)
  clusterExport(cl, c("dataall", "est_func","n","covariates","p","a","astar","Deriv"))
  outbootfunc = boot::boot(data = dataall, statistic = est_func,  R = replications,bootcond=1, parallel = "snow",ncpus = mycores-1)
```

I keep getting the error with object 'covariates' not found:

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  10 nodes produced errors; first error: object 'covariates' not found
```

I understand lots of similar questions have been asked previously but still, I fail to work around with this. I have not provided the function 'est_func' as it is quite complicated but if needed I will modify the question.

Thanks!

Comment: Quick comment: I doubt that `boot::boot()` is making use of your parallel cluster `cl`.  Instead, I suspect it ends up creating its own based on `parallel = "snow",ncpus = mycores-1`. In other words, what ever you export to your `cl` cluster makes no difference. Check `?boot::boot`.

Comment: That was my understanding. But even without using the `clusterexport` function I keep getting the same error!

Comment: Yes, that's expected. Whatever you do with `cl` has nothing to do with it. Drop all your code that involves `cl`.  Then look at `?boot::boot`.  If their documentation does not explain how to "object not found" errors, reach out to their community or the maintainer.